# How to get all matches from regex?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I would like to get all occurrences of `[0-9A-Z]+?` for processing later.
I do have

```
if [[ `cat file` =~ '[0-9A-Z]+?' ]]; then
  echo $BASH_REMATCH;
fi
```

Which gives me first match, but how could I process all the matches in the file?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to add the ? at the end of the pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get just the matched text of a regular expression, I would use

```
grep -o 'regex' file
```

In the spirit of your code I would modify it to be

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ regex ]] || continue
    # do somethinw with $line or $BASH_REMATCH, perhaps put it in an array.
done < file
```

If you want to match multiple regexes on the same line, here is a way.

```
while read line; do
    # do somethinw with $line
done < <(grep -o 'regex' file)
```

I assume your regex is supposed to be a simplified example of what your really doing. The ? is not helpfull and your quotes are matching a literal string.

Comment: The regex is slightly more complex, +? is needed to be lazy.
Even though the "while ... done < file" is what I needed, greatly appreciated, didn't know where to look.

Thank you

Comment: What if one line contains the regex match twice?
How can I process that?