# Extract regex from file using linux utility.  print each match on a seperate line

Tags: xml, regex, linux, sed, awk

I am trying to extract values from a file using a regular expresion.

I have 2 xml files.  Each one is composed of lots of hotspots which has attributes `X`and `Y`, (coordinates), like:

```
 <HOTSPOT ID="476" NAME="19.328" MEDIATYPE="url" MEDIA="/flash/hiddenHotspot.png" X="1427" Y="1989" WIDTH="280" HEIGHT="280" ZOOM="83" XSCALE="300" YSCALE="300" URL="/archive/manuscripts/1/decode?detail=476&amp;page=0" URLTARGET="_self" ROLLOVER="0" CAPTION="328" TOOLTIP="">
    <TOOLTIP>&lt;b&gt;19.328&lt;/b&gt;.&lt;br&gt;&lt;p class="poem1"&gt;In the Year 10 House, on the Day 11 Monkey,&lt;/p&gt;</TOOLTIP>
  </HOTSPOT>
```

I am trying to extract just the X value from the file.  I started with grep but it returns the full lines.  My regex is just `/X="([0-9]+)"/`.  I am on ubuntu 12.04.  I'm sure that one of these built in utilities can help but I have not been able to find which one.

Is there a way to just print to stdout the matches of my regex using a linux utility? Each match should be on a seperate line?  Could someone please point me in the right direction? Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -o` with regex pattern `(?<=\bX=")([^"]+)(?=")`

Comment: ty, which utitlity should i use to run the regex pattern you suggested?

Comment: @dm03514 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642067/how-to-get-all-matches-from-regex

Comment: ty i just figured it out `grep -o`, if you can update answer will accept as soon as they allow me to